# Parsing XML chunks in a non-XML file

Tags: xml-parsing, edge-side-includes

Can anyone share experience with parsing XML chunks embedded in a non-XML file?

I am implementing an Edge-Side-Includes[1] processor. Edge-Side-Includes elements are not necessarily embedded in XML- or well-formed XML files and this poses the question, how to go about finding and then parsing such elements.

Has anyone done something similar?

[1] http://www.w3.org/TR/esi-lang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the best option is to either embed the XML tokenizing into the overall tokenizer or identify the chunks and hand them to an XML parser individually.